# Creating Organization on Azure Dev Ops with existing name

Tags: azure-devops

I have created an organization on Azure DevOps with my email id ( created by me) which is the same as my email id associated with my azure subscription.

I want to create an organization with the name and URL what I created with my personal account in Microsoft associated account.

I deleted one which I created and tried creating by login as a Work Account, however, I get an error organization already exits.

How can I get it resolved?

Comment: Hi @Manoj Deshmukh Did check out below answer from Anduin, how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps can be linked to an Azure Active Directory. In your situation, I strongly suggest you do the following steps to link it and transfer the ownership to your work account:

1. Make sure you can fully control both your work account and your personal Microsoft account.
2. Link your existing Azure DevOps organization to your Azure Active Directory.
3. Add your work account as an administrator in your Azure DevOps organization.
4. Transfer the ownership of the organization to your work account.
5. Kick your personal account out.

#### Here are some tips:

You can link existing Azure Active Directory like this:

[image]

You can change the ownership of your Azure DevOps organization like this:

[image]

#### Backup solution

Of course, you can delete the entire Azure DevOps organization and recreate it. To delete it, make sure all your data is safe. And press the `Delete` button in the `Overview` settings.

[image]

After deleting it and you can re-create a new organization with the same name using your work account.